Disposition of ovals in the projective plane
Consider a curve in the projective plane. It is a one-dimensional compact manifold, and each of its components is homomorphic to a circle. Then, there are two different ways to embed it in the projective plane: as the boundary of a disk (even oval) or as a projective line (odd oval).
I cannot prove why a curve with an odd degree admits only one odd-oval, and also it is not very clear the geometric intuition behind.

Do you know the classification theorem for surfaces? It should be a reasonably straightforward application of that theorem.
